# Is there a way to display an element as just a plain text in HTML?

Tags: html, element

I need to have this as an output:

`New element <Canada> inserted.`

I tried doing this:

```
<p>New element <Canada> inserted.</p>
```

But I end up with this:

```
New element inserted.
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do this. I would use the HTML-entities:

```
<p>New element &lt;Canada&gt; inserted.</p>
```

[A short lesson about HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that

```
<p>New element &lt;Canada&gt; inserted.</p>
```

Comment: this will not work

Comment: Sorry i didnt show as code